# SSIS crash after few records

Tags: sql, visual-studio, sql-server-2008, ssis

I have an SSIS package which suppose to take 100,000 records loop on them and for each one save the details to few tables.
It's working fine, until it reaches somewhere near the 3000 records, then the visual studio crashes. At this point devenv.exe used about 500MB and only 3000 rows were processed.
I'm sure the problem is not with a specific record because it always happens on different 3K of records.
I have a good computer with 2 GIG of ram available.
I'm using SSIS 2008.

Any idea what might be the issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Does it do the same thing in dtexec/dtexecui?

Comment: I didn't check. I use the designer to run it.

Comment: What error does it throw when it crashes? Could you post a screenshot of the control flow and then the data flow(s)?

Comment: That's the problem: no error, just all the designer closes.

Comment: No error when you run the package from the command line via dtexec?

Comment: I ran it now with dtexecui and it ran fine but very very slow. I don't know why.

Comment: when i say it ran fine means i couldn't wait this long for it to process 3k rows. very slow.

Comment: Now I ran it with the correct version of dtexec, and it runs fast and doesn't get stuck! Thanks.

Comment: We would need more deatil to really suggest something, but if you are using a merge join which requires a sort, that is often the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing the default buffer size on your data flow tasks.

Example given here: http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1867/sql-server-integration-services-ssis-performance-best-practices/

**Best Practice #7 - DefaultBufferMaxSize and DefaultBufferMaxRows**

> As I said in the "Best Practices #6", the execution tree creates
>   buffers for storing incoming rows and performing transformations. So
>   how many buffers does it create? How many rows fit into a single
>   buffer? How does it impact performance?
>
> The number of buffer created is dependent on how many rows fit into a
>   buffer and how many rows fit into a buffer dependent on few other
>   factors. The first consideration is the estimated row size, which is
>   the sum of the maximum sizes of all the columns from the incoming
>   records. The second consideration is the DefaultBufferMaxSize property
>   of the data flow task.  This property specifies the default maximum
>   size of a buffer. **The default value is 10 MB** and its upper and lower
>   boundaries are constrained by two internal properties of SSIS which
>   are **MaxBufferSize (100MB)** and **MinBufferSize (64 KB)**. It means the size
>   of a buffer can be as small as 64 KB and as large as 100 MB. The third
>   factor is, **DefaultBufferMaxRows which is again a property of data flow**
>   task which specifies the default number of rows in a buffer.  Its
>   **default value is 10000**.
>
> Although SSIS does a good job in tuning for these properties in order
>   to create a optimum number of buffers, if the size exceeds the
>   DefaultBufferMaxSize then it reduces the rows in the buffer. For
>   better buffer performance you can do two things.  First you can remove
>   unwanted columns from the source and set data type in each column
>   appropriately, especially if your source is flat file.  This will
>   enable you to accommodate as many rows as possible in the buffer.
>   Second, if your system has sufficient memory available, you can tune
>   these properties to have a small number of large buffers, which could
>   improve performance. Beware if you change the values of these
>   properties to a point where page spooling (see Best Practices #8)
>   begins, it adversely impacts performance. So before you set a value
>   for these properties, first thoroughly testing in your environment and
>   set the values appropriately.
>
> You can enable logging of the BufferSizeTuning event to learn how many
>   rows a buffer contains and you can monitor "Buffers spooled"
>   performance counter to see if the SSIS has began page spooling.  I
>   will talk more about event logging and performance counters in my next
>   tips of this series.